# How do I connect a spinner to work with a unit converter?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, converters

I have this project to make a unit converter and I have to use a spinner. In my code I have a temperature converter which works but I am using radio buttons in that. After that I setup another unit converter that converts feet,meters,yards,miles to feet,meters,yards, miles. I am very close to finishing it but I am not sure how to do my if statement so that if(feet is selected && yards is selected on my second spinner) to make it work. I will provide the code below.

```
public class UnitConverterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
************
EditText temp;
EditText temp2;
RadioButton toC;
RadioButton toF;
Spinner spinner;
Spinner spinner1;
************
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unit_converter);
    *************************************************
    //casting my xml buttons
    temp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TemperatureEditText);
    temp2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.LengthEditText);
    toC = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.toCelsiusRadioButton);
    toF = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.toFarenheitRadioButton);
    //casting my xml buttons

    //spinner first
    String[] length={"Feet", "Meters", "Miles", "Yards"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    length);
    Spinner spinner =
            (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.firstSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

    //spinner first

    //spinner second
    String[] length1={"Feet", "Meters", "Miles", "Yards"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter1=
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    length1);
    Spinner spinner1 =
            (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
    spinner1.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter1);

    //spinner second
    **********************************************

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",  Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_unit_converter, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
***********************************************************
public void convert(View v){
    double value= new Double(temp.getText().toString());
    if(toC.isChecked()){
            value = UnitConverter.farenheit2Celsius(value);
    }
    else {
        value= UnitConverter.celsius2Farenheit(value);
    }
    temp.setText(new Double(value).toString());

}

public void convertTo(View v){
double value= new Double(temp2.getText().toString());
    if(spinner.isSelected() && spinner1.isSelected()){
        value=UnitConverter.feetToFeet(value);
    }
    temp2.setText(new Double(value).toString());
}
******************************************************
}
```

the parts that is surrounded by ***** is my code.

the convertTo() method is what I am trying to make work.
If you can just show me for 1 example I can figure out the rest.

This is my UnitConverter class I made for all of my formulas.

```
package com.plamen.unitconverter;


 * Created by Plamen on 1/31/2016.
 */
public class UnitConverter {
public static double celsius2Farenheit(double c){
    return 32+c*9/5;
}
public static double farenheit2Celsius(double f){

    return (f-32)*5/9;
}

//length conversion
public static double feetToFeet(double f){
    return f;
}
public static double feetToMeters(double f){
    return f*0.3058;
}
public static double feetToYards(double f){
    return f*0.333333;
}
public static double feetToMiles(double f){
    return f*0.000189394;
}
public static double yardsToFeet(double y){
    return y/0.333333;
}
public static double yardsToYards(double y){
    return y;
}
public static double yardsToMeters(double y){
    return y*0.9144;
}
public static double yardsToMiles(double y){
    return y*0.000568182;
}
public static double metersToFeet(double m){
    return m*3.28084;
}
public static double metersToYards(double m){
    return m*1.09361;
}
public static double metersToMeters(double m){
    return m;
}
public static double metersToMiles(double m){
    return m*0.000621371;
}
public static double milesToFeet(double miles){
    return miles*5280;
}
public static double milesToYards(double miles){
    return miles*1760;
}
public static double milesToMeters(double miles){
    return miles*1609.34;
}
public static double milesToMiles(double miles){
    return miles;
}
//length conversion
}
```

[image: This is what my application layout looks like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate your transformation by the selected indeces. Just add a onitemselected listener to your spinners.

1. Add OnItemSelectedListener
   `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`
2. implement interface to your class

   `public MyClass implements OnItemSelectedListener{`
3. Override OnItemSelectedListener in your class

   `@Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   *CODE HERE* 
   }`
4. You can find out which spinner is selected by `view.getId()==R.id.spinner` or `view.getId()==R.id.spinner1` . Best practice would be a switch case.
5. the int position will be the selected index of the spinner
6. Now just put your custom code and the logic inside and it will work

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Hope it helps